# How can I check from the command line if a reboot is required on RHEL or CentOS?

Tags: centos, redhat, yum, update, rhel5

I'm using CentOS and Red Hat Enterprise Linux on a few machines without the GUI. How can I check if recently installed updates require a reboot? In Ubuntu, I'm used to checking if `/var/run/reboot-required` is present.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3106621#comment-1196821

> Don't forget that you might need to reboot because of core library updates, at least if it is glibc. (And also, services may need to be restarted after updates).
>
> If you install the `yum-utils` package, you can use a command called `needs-restarting`.
>
> You can use it both for checking if a full reboot is required because of kernel or core libraries updates (using the `-r` option), or what services need to be restarted (using the `-s` option).
>
> `needs-restarting -r` returns `0` if reboot is not needed, and `1` if it is, so it is perfect to use in a script.
>
> An example:

```
root@server1:~> needs-restarting  -r ; echo $?
Core libraries or services have been updated:
  openssl-libs -> 1:1.0.1e-60.el7_3.1
  systemd -> 219-30.el7_3.9

Reboot is required to ensure that your system benefits from these updates.

More information:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/27943
1
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that at least the `-s` option requires root access.

Comment: For Fedora, `needs-restarting` is [an DNF plugin](https://dnf-plugins-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/needs_restarting.html). It doesn’t support `-r` or `-s` (yet).

Comment: CentOS 6 doesn't support `-r`, either, and the `needs-restarting` it has is not good enough (doesn't notice when a newer kernel is available).

Comment: `$?` still is `1`, even so `needs-restarting -r` says `No core libraries or services have been updated.`

Answer (score 39):

About comparing installed kernels with running one:

```
#!/bin/bash
LAST_KERNEL=$(rpm -q --last kernel | perl -pe 's/^kernel-(\S+).*/$1/' | head -1)
CURRENT_KERNEL=$(uname -r)

test $LAST_KERNEL = $CURRENT_KERNEL || echo REBOOT
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: At first I thought this wasn't working as it continued to tell me to reboot after I had, but then found out that if you are using a DigitalOcean instance, you need to manually change the kernel from their control panel first before rebooting.

Comment: Is there a reason why the `kernel-` string is being removed from the output of `rpm -q`?

Comment: The `kernel-` string must be removed to compare it with the output from `uname -r`, which doesn't contain it.

Answer (score 8):

You could compare the ouput of uname -a with the list of installed kernel packages

Comment: Is a different kernel the only reason a linux server would *need* a reboot?

Comment: Normally, when staying within the 'normal' package upgrade processes (up2date, yum etc.), there shouldn't be really many other reasons to reboot the system besides the kernel upgrade

Comment: I suspect that certain other packages may require a reboot eben iof the kernel does not change (when I installed kexec-tools-2.0.0-258 on centos6.0 there was no memory reserved for the dump)

Comment: BeyondTrust's pbis-open package requests the user to reboot after installation via stdout.

Answer (score 8):

One thing that can be helpful to look at in terms of "is a reboot required" is whether or not there are any files that have been removed/replaced by the update but for which the old files are still loaded/used by active processes.

Basically, when YUM updates a file that is in use by a process, the file itself may have been marked for deletion, but the process keeps using the old file since it has an open file-descriptor to the old file's inode.

A command to get a count of the number of old files still in use:

```
#lsof | grep "(path inode=.*)" | wc -l
```

That command will give you a count of the files.

Use this instead to see which files are actually in use:

```
#lsof | grep "(path inode=.*)"
```

That command will produce output similar to the following on a YUM-updated box:

```
COMMAND    PID   USER   FD      TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
sshd      3782   root  mem       REG   8,17          153427 /lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8e (path inode=153253)
mysqld    3883  mysql  mem       REG   8,17          153259 /lib64/libcrypt-2.5.so (path inode=153402)
mingetty  4107   root  mem       REG   8,17          153243 /lib64/libc-2.5.so (path inode=153222)
...
etc
```

Comment: Is this a reliable way to detect kernel updates (obviating the need for me also to check that)?

Answer (score 7):

`uname -a` vs. `rpm -q kernel` and `needs-restarting` from `yum-utils`

Answer (score 3):

Check whether running kernel is the latest one.

If it's not, check whether system was restarted since kernel install.

If it was not, reboot.

```
CURRENT_KERNEL="$(rpm -q kernel-$(uname -r))"
test -z "$CURRENT_KERNEL" && exit 0     # Current kernel is a custom kernel

LATEST_KERNEL="$(rpm -q kernel | tail -1)"
test -z "$LATEST_KERNEL" && exit 0      # No kernel package installed

LATEST_KERNEL_INSTALLTIME=$(rpm -q kernel --qf "%{INSTALLTIME}\n" | tail -1)
test -z "$LATEST_KERNEL_INSTALLTIME" && exit 1      # Error reading INSTALLTIME

test "$CURRENT_KERNEL" = "$LATEST_KERNEL" && exit 0 # Latest kernel running, no reboot needed

BOOTTIME="$(sed -n '/^btime /s///p' /proc/stat)"
test -z "$BOOTTIME" && exit 1           # Error reading BOOTTIME

test "$LATEST_KERNEL_INSTALLTIME" -lt "$BOOTTIME" && exit 1 # Latest kernel not running, but system was restarted already
                                        # User switched back to an old kernel?

echo reboot
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you have a PAE enabled kernel version. The uname -r comamnd returns the PAE suffix after the .elX part but not the rpm names.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has been answered already and that folks have posted information about checking for newer kernels as well as deleted files, but I recently wrote a script that checks for both.  If either condition is detected, the reboot is scheduled for +30 minutes.

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

NEW_KERN=0
DEAD_FILES=0

die () {
    printf "Error, exiting: "
    echo $@
    exit 1
}

for X in lsof wc column awk rpm sed head uname dd tr cut date logger shutdown; do
    which "${X}" >/dev/null 2>&1 || die "required application ${X} not found"
done

DATEY="$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)"
TMPFILE=/tmp/"$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1 count=256 2>/dev/null |tr -c -d '0-9a-f' |cut -c-7)"

[ $TMPFILE == "/tmp/" ] && die
echo "### Reboot automation notice: ${DATEY} ###" > "${TMPFILE}"
lsof +c0 -d DEL | grep -v '\s/SYSV' |awk 'NR==1 || !/dev\/zero/ {print $2,$1,$4,$NF}' | column -t >> "${TMPFILE}"

if [ $(cat ${TMPFILE} |wc -l) -gt 2 ]; then
    DEAD_FILES=1
else
    echo "### Reboot automation notice: ${DATEY} ###" > "${TMPFILE}"
fi

C_KERN="kernel-$(uname -r)"
A_KERN="$(rpm -q --last kernel |head -1 |sed 's|\s\+.*$||')"

[ $A_KERN != $C_KERN ] && NEW_KERN=1 && printf "Running $C_KERN, but $A_KERN available\n" >> "${TMPFILE}"

echo "### End of reboot automation notice: ${DATEY} ###" >> "${TMPFILE}"
if [[ $DEAD_FILES -eq 0 && $NEW_KERN -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo reboot not required
else
    logger -t rebooter -p auth.warning -f "${TMPFILE}"
    [ $DEAD_FILES -ne 0 ] && echo "   Processes running with broken links to executables,"
    [ $NEW_KERN -ne 0 ] && echo "   New kernel available,"
    echo Reboot is required
    shutdown -r +30 "System reboot is required.  To cancel use shutdown -c.  But don't because this system needs to be rebooted"
fi

[ -f "${TMPFILE}" ] && rm -f "${TMPFILE}"
```

#### 2020-07-15 Update

Since originally writing this answer, I've improved and updated the script.  It is available on github here: https://github.com/qth/jutil/blob/master/rbc

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version of the alexm code.
You can do this:

```
LAST_KERNEL=$(rpm -q --last kernel | perl -pe 's/^kernel-(\S+).*/$1/' | head -1)
 CURRENT_KERNEL=$(uname -r)

 if [ $LAST_KERNEL != $CURRENT_KERNEL ]
 then 
    echo "It is time to Reboot!"
 else 
    echo "There is nothing to do!"
 fi
```

Answer (score -7):

install.log install.log.syslog  yum.log you check this place what all got new rpm got install